# How to Upload AudioBuffer to google cloud storage without losing header info

Tags: node.js, audio, google-cloud-storage, wav

Hello I have been trying to solve this problem for more than a month and no progress.
I am trying record some audio in the browser and then upload the audio into google cloud storage. Those all works fine, I can record audio and play it in google cloud storage. however no matter what I did when I download the file I found out the RIFF header have been lost.
For example

```
    'Expected "RIFF" string at 0',
    'Expected "WAVE" string at 4',
    'Expected "fmt " string at 8',
    'Unknown format: 16904',
    'chunk_size does not match file size'
```

The way I store my recorded audio is blob. My frontend is React and backend is Nodejs. So what I did is to send the blob to the backend. Like below. And calling readfile to read the data into buffer

```
router.post("/audio", upload.any(), async (req, res) => {
const { Storage } = require("@google-cloud/storage");
  const storage = new Storage();
  const audioBucket = storage.bucket("xxxxxx");
  const file = audioBucket.file("audio.wav");

  fs.readFile(req.files[0].path, null, (err, data) => {

    file.save(data, function (err) {
      file.get().then(function (data1) {
        console.log(data1);
      });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation there are several way to make [`upload`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploads-downloads) request to GCP:

- `Single-request upload`: For small files.
- `Resumable upload`: For reliable transfers which are used for large files.
- `XML API multipart upload`: Upload method that is compatible with Amazon S3.

I suggest you to use the client library of Node.js to upload your audio. You can do that by using the [`createWriteStream()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#createWriteStream) method. Here is the example provided by the documentation on how to use this method:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();
const myBucket = storage.bucket('my-bucket');

const file = myBucket.file('my-file');

//-
// <h4>Uploading a File</h4>
//
// Now, consider a case where we want to upload a file to your bucket. You
// have the option of using Bucket#upload, but that is just
// a convenience method which will do the following.
//-
fs.createReadStream('/Users/stephen/Photos/birthday-at-the-zoo/panda.jpg')
  .pipe(file.createWriteStream())
  .on('error', function(err) {})
  .on('finish', function() {
    // The file upload is complete.
  });

//-
// <h4>Uploading a File with gzip compression</h4>
//-
fs.createReadStream('/Users/stephen/site/index.html')
  .pipe(file.createWriteStream({ gzip: true }))
  .on('error', function(err) {})
  .on('finish', function() {
    // The file upload is complete.
  });

//-
// Downloading the file with `createReadStream` will automatically decode
// the file.
//-

//-
// <h4>Uploading a File with Metadata</h4>
//
// One last case you may run into is when you want to upload a file to your
// bucket and set its metadata at the same time. Like above, you can use
// Bucket#upload to do this, which is just a wrapper around
// the following.
//-
fs.createReadStream('/Users/stephen/Photos/birthday-at-the-zoo/panda.jpg')
  .pipe(file.createWriteStream({
    metadata: {
      contentType: 'image/jpeg',
      metadata: {
        custom: 'metadata'
      }
    }
  }))
  .on('error', function(err) {})
  .on('finish', function() {
    // The file upload is complete.
  });
```